# how can a class or interface can extend more than one class in java

Tags: interface, multiple-inheritance

how can a class or interface can extend more than one class in java Please help..

`Steps:::javap java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime` in cmd prompt

Compiled from "ChronoLocalDateTime.java"

```
public interface java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime<D extends java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate> ex
tends java.time.temporal.Temporal, java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjuster,
```

Comment: your class can implement multiple interfaces, but extending from more than one class is not possible. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/multipleinheritance.html

Comment: thanks for immediate help..

Answer (score 0):

Excepting Object, which has no superclass, every class has one and only one direct superclass (single inheritance). In the absence of any other explicit superclass, every class is implicitly a subclass of Object.

if you need multiherence you need implements interfaces

look this
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html